# Layout stays blank

Tags: android, error-handling, rendering, xml-layout

I have added an `ImageView` and two TextFields to my Layout but when I look in the preview it just stays blank. It gives me the error "Rendering error". What can I do?

I will add my Layout file in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RealtiveLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorSlide_1" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wireless"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/slide_1_title"
    android:textColor="android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/slide_title"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/slide_1_desc"
    android:textColor="android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/slide_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/slide_desc"
    android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    />

</RealtiveLayout>
```

Comment: @NileshRathod Because i have not worked with Android Studio yet I Need to know where I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this below changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorSlide_1"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wireless"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"//or you use wrap_content
    android:text="@string/slide_1_title"
    android:textColor="android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/slide_title"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/slide_1_desc"
    android:textColor="android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/slide_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/slide_desc"
    android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you help me a second time? When I start this application it gives me an error with the line:  Android:textColor="Android:color/White    How can I solve this?

Comment: use like this android:textColor="@android:color/white" ...
If you stored in color file of your project then you use as android:textColor="@color/white"

Answer (score 1):

Change `RealtiveLayout` to `RelativeLayout` in your root Layout.

Comment: ooops... you are right. But my second text field still does not Show up. Do ypu knwo how to solve?

Comment: change the width of your `TextView` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your code .@MIsterX

Comment: Change the height of your TextView in your code .@MIsterX

Comment: I havent got 15 reputation so this isnt possible

Comment: Good luck to you .@MIsterX

Comment: What are you doing now ? @MIsterX